# Website for travel suggestions in a given week with a given budget

Tags: recommendations

I'm looking for a website that gives me travel advices, based on the following 
information:

1. City of departure. Ex: Stockholm
2. Budget for flight tickets. Ex: 1000 euros
3. Travelers. Ex: 2 adults + 2 kids
4. Earliest departure date. Ex: 14 July, but it could be some days later.
5. Latest return date. Ex. 21 July, but it could be some days before.

So, for instance, if the website suggests a trip Stockholm-Paris-Stockholm from 15 to 19 july that would be perfectly fine.

The closest I found was momondo trip finder. The problem is that it only gives
suggestions on a specific month. It seems that it is not possible to find flights in a given week.

Answer (score 2):

https://adioso.com/ will do most of what you want. You can set departure airport to "Stockhom" and destination to "anwyhere", "internatianol" or "europe". Departure date to to a range (say Jul 14 to Jul 17) and length to "about 5 days".

You may have to play around with the dates and duration a bit to get exactly what you want. Internationally, it looks like cities like Berlin, Palma, Brussels, Copenhagen, Nice, etc. are within your price range.

For example Palma de Mallorca from Jul 15 to Jul 21 comes in at around Euro 229 per person on Expedia